# friend functions and declarations

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

I had class which had a friend function for example if the header was:

```
 class A{
       friend void foo();
       public:
             A(){}
 };

 void foo();
```

So what I cannot get is what does the compiler do with the second declaration?

I've all so noticed I can write as many of them as I want with no effect, e.g

```
void foo();
void foo();
...
```

(Assume the implementation is in the cpp file)

Plus I couldn't find where does the standard say the declaring some function as a friend also declares the function itself.

Comment: I think you're missing what a friend function actually does.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Beyond friend functions, I think there's some confusion on how functions work in general. Declaration, definition, and friending are fairly different and do entirely different things.

Comment: @TylerJandreau Nope I'm well aware of its purpose just was curious when does it count as a declaration of the friend function and not just the "befriending" of a function and a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `friend` declaration were the *only* declaration, then the function would be in the surrounding namespace, but couldn't be found by the normal lookup rules; it could only be found by *argument dependent lookup*.

In this case, it means that it couldn't be found at all, since there are no arguments; so you also need a declaration in the namespace to make it accessible.

Sometimes you want that behaviour; for example, a streaming operator can be found by ADL without declaring it in the namespace:

```
struct A {
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, A const & a) {
        return s << "Hello";
    }
};

A a;
std::cout << a;   // finds the friend function by ADL, based on the argument 'a'
```

> I've all so noticed I can write as many of them as I want with no effect

Yes, you can repeat declarations as many times as you like.

> Plus I couldn't find where does the standard say the declaring some function as a friend also declares the function itself.

Most of the specification for declarations (C++11 clause 7) is the same whether or not the declaration contains a `friend` specifier. 7.3.1.2/3 specifies that the name is in the namespace, not the class, and also specifies the lookup rules.

Answer (score 3):

```
friend void foo();
```

This declearation simply tells the compiler that somewhere you have a function `void foo()` and that function will be able to access all the members of your class.
And how many times you write:

```
void foo();
void foo();
```

This won't effect because this is prototype of `foo()` not definition of `foo()`. Somewhere you have to write a body of `foo()` otherwise any call to `foo()` will fail